# Incompatible packages with MRO on anaconda

Tags: r, anaconda, method-resolution-order

I have some complicated code in R that uses the neuralnet library for some computations.
Sorrily, I'm new to R and I'have less than a week to obtain some results using the existing code, which take quite a while in the processors I have to my disposal.

My idea is to implement the code via microsoft R open (**MRO**), which could accelerate the computations, but I haven't been able to install the neuralnet library via anaconda (I prefer anaconda because it's simple and allows to create environments easily). The installation goes with "Solving environment" forever.

Is there a way to install these libraries to be compatible with MRO on anaconda?? should i desist of using anaconda for this task?

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but have you considered changing how your modeling is working? Can you sample a smaller subset? Remove some features? I point this way, because it may be a better skill in the long run than the setup for an ad-hoc run with new technology.

Comment: I have. In fact, that is what i'm doing, but it is still quite inefficient in terms of running the model, and in time because there are a lot of observations.